# A word to describe movie that is shown only on internet

Tags: single-word-requests

Is is ok to use the word "internet movie" for a movie that people have to pay money online and view only on internet, actually view only on any device that can connect to internet and play movie file.

Example.

The hirer agrees to hire the actor and the actor agrees to be hired as actor to play an internet movie. (hereinafter referred to as “The internet movie”).

Comment: If it can't be downloaded, I'd call it a *streaming-only movie*.  Since I like alliteration and term-coining a bit too much, I feel inclined to also offer *packet picture*.

Comment: Do you mean something made for Netflix (or other subscription streaming service like Disney+, Amazon Prime, etc), or something on YouTube or TikTok or social media, or something where you have to download a file from a website? There are some specific terms used for individual platforms (people talk about a Netflix film/movie, and may talk about watching a YouTube or a TikTok) but I'm not sure there's a general term across all platforms for movies in particular (as distinct to vlogs or video podcasts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a movie released ONLY on the internet, then you may possibly call it a **netcast**. The term is not widely popular and you are always better off explaining in a full sentence.

Comment: should i say only netcast or netcast movie

Comment: The word 'netcast' itself suggest that it is a movie or a play (online).

Comment: A question: The term *webcast* has the sense of [being "live"](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=9&gs_id=y&xhr=t&q=webcast+definition&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=webcast+d&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6b4b1bdf32659c2&biw=1366&bih=552) (though I know webcasts also can be recorded and then pushed out later). Does *netcast* have that same sense?

Comment: @JLG: The word is just a portmanteau (and trimming) of internet and broadcast. Also the notion of a live broadcast does not apply very much to movies.

Comment: If that is so, wouldn't Sarawut want to use the word "movie" too (*netcast movie*)?

Comment: I would think netcast could apply to more than movies – for example, a newscast.

Comment: Netcast definitely isn't specific to movies. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/netcast) defines it as a synonym of "webcast", "A video broadcast of an event transmitted over the internet." This suggests broadcasting something that's happening already, like a sports game or an awards show.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a legal document- a contract.  You need to think clearly about what you are attempting to say here- What rights are you assigning and what are you attempting to prevent. There are lots of holes in all the suggestions I've read here so far. 
Don't rely on any terms like *netcast*, *internet movie*- define the parameters for distribution etc. explicitly in your contract and then assign a name to it. Once defined you could then just refer to it thereafter as "the movie" and be done with it.  But I suggest you consult a lawyer-  If you are worried enough to make a contract and have it signed then you ought to have a contract that *holds water*.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context.  By itself, the phrase "*internet movie*" is using "internet" as an adjective to describe "movie."  If I saw that term, I'd assume that the movie was available for streaming, but I wouldn't necessarily think, "that movie is available *exclusively* over the internet."

However, in a context such as the one you provide ("*The actor agrees to take a role for an upcoming internet movie*") I'd assume that the movie will be released as a streaming film (although that wouldn't necessarily preclude the movie from being released on DVD some time down the road).

The term doesn't infer that viewers would have to pay to watch the movie, though.  If you wanted that conveyed as well, you'd have to say something like:

> The actor has agreed to take a role for an upcoming pay-per-view internet movie.

or,

> The actor has agreed to take a role for an upcoming internet movie, which will be available to subscribers only.

It's a complicated question, because word choice depends on the available payment options, too.

Comment: i put the example already.

Comment: Thanks for providing the example – that helps a lot.  Now I need to revise my answer! :^)

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question, I must admit.

As suggested by Shyam, netcast sounds pretty accurate. I have also come across the use of 'community video' for internet-only releases of films. Pay-per-view (not specific to a movie though) might be another option you may consider but you say that it is released only over internet, so PPV wouldn't be the best choice.